# log4cplus logs in Visual Studio debug console

Tags: c++, qt, log4cplus

How do I force log4cplus logs to show in Visual Studio 2013 debug console ? This is Qt application, standard ConsoleAppender does not write anything, RollingFileAppender works fine. There's also QtDebugAppender but it does not write to debug console.

Comment: Except Qt there is nothing standard for Qt in your message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`Win32DebugAppender`](https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus/blob/master/include/log4cplus/win32debugappender.h). It uses `OutputDebugString()`.